# Is it possible to check rendered page content in wp_enqueu_scripts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to optimize asset loading of a plugin that I do not own. The plugin adds content to pages via shortcodes that may or may not contain conditionals that I am after. I need to somehow get the content fully rendered inside `wp_enqueu_scripts` and do regex to determine if assets should be loaded. Is this possible?

So far I have tried:

`get_the_content()` - only shows unrendered names of shortcodes.

`the_content` filter hook - runs after `wp_enqueu_scripts` so does not work.

`the_content()` function - actually echoes the content which is no good for just a check.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to get the rendered content is applying the `the_content` filter to the content. This way:

```
$id = 0;
$content = get_the_content($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

All the filters that are registered will run, so also the shortcodes that have already been added. In case these are not added yet, you should revert to using javascript on the frontend to tackle the problem.